# Keystore-java inputstream

Tags: java, keystore

In the below code,why we using FileInputStream?For what purpose?Don't say refer java docs,wiki or anything.
I need a practical answer.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
// get user password and file input stream
char[] password = getPassword();

java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
    ks.load(fis, password);
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: To read data from a file ?

Comment: Because [`keyStore.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#load%28java.io.InputStream,%20char[]%29) takes `InputStream` as method parameter ?

Comment: Why? it takes thats my question

Comment: So that it can read data from it? Into the keystore? Is this really so mysterious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyStore.load` does not take a `FileInputStream`. It takes an `InputStream` as a parameter and since `FileInputStream` extends `InputStream` you can pass it as a parameter. Why does the KeyStore require an input stream? Because the keystore saves its structure as a stream of bytes. For getting the stored state back, there should be a mechanism to load from some place. The `KeyStore` designers decided to use `InputStream` as the right choice. They could easily have designed a load method that takes a `byte[]` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

it takes input stream as a parameter for reading the cacerts file which is truststore.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load the specified Keystore in filestream.